# How to allow arrays as inputs for javascript function in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, user-input

So I started learning html/css/js recently and I know that the end-goal for me is to be able to apply it realistically and using an IDE just felt redundant, as I am now more curious about how I can apply all the js code in a useful way within an html document.

With that said, I am working on some basic js algos but I want to be able to convert the problem into a webpage instead of using an IDE and the question I am currently on is this:

Write a function that takes two or more arrays and returns a new array of unique values in the order of the original provided arrays.

for example:

uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]) should return [1, 3, 2, 5, 4]

for my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
      <title>MFW</title>
   </head>

   <body>
   <p>Click the button to enter values.</p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <script src="js/script.js"> 
  </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

And for my js code:

```
function myFunction() {
  let arr = [];
  let arr2 = [];
  var args = prompt("Please enter number of arrays");
  for(let i=0; i<args; i++){
    let realI = Number(i);

    let currentArr = prompt('Enter elements for array ' + (realI+1));
    arr[i] = currentArr;

  }
  for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
     let currentArr = arr[i];
     for(let j=0; j<currentArr.length; j++){
        
        if(arr2.includes(currentArr[j])){
           arr2=arr2;
        }
        else{
           arr2.append(currentArr[j]);
        }
     }
  }
  alert(arr2);
}
```

every step of the way I kept testing to make sure the *alert* method worked
but for some reason when I write the last for statement, the alert does not show my result. Can someone please help? Also, if there is some resource I can look at to better understand what I want to accomplish that would be awesome.

Answer (score 3):

You can take advantage of the following functions and syntax for significantly shorter code.

[Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

[Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and [Includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

This `uniteUnique` function will accept any number of arguments and return a new array with unique values:

```js
function uniteUnique(...arrs) {
  return arrs.reduce((a, c) => [...a, ...c.filter(i => !a.includes(i))], []);
}

let r = uniteUnique([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1])

console.log(r)
```

Comment: but i just have a question.. how can i get the input for r?

Answer (score 1):

There were two issues identified in your code.

1. You have used a function called `append`. You need to use the `push` function JavaScript arrays in order to append values into an array.
2. Commas are also being pushed to the 2nd array. You can remove them by adding an `if` condition.

```js
function myFunction() {
  let arr = [];
  let arr2 = [];
  var args = prompt("Please enter number of arrays");
  for(let i=0; i<args; i++){
    let realI = Number(i);

    let currentArr = prompt('Enter elements for array ' + (realI+1));
    arr[i] = currentArr;

  }
  for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
     let currentArr = arr[i];
     
     for(let j=0; j<currentArr.length; j++){
        
        if(arr2.includes(currentArr[j])){
           arr2=arr2;
        }
        else{
           if (currentArr[j] !== ","){
            arr2.push(currentArr[j]);
           }
           
        }
     }
  }
  alert(arr2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
      <title>MFW</title>
   </head>

   <body>
   <p>Click the button to enter values.</p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <script src="js/script.js"> 
  </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you. i completely forgot i was doing js and not java